# Asynchronous call to WCF service from MVC controller

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a restful WCF service that I need to call asynchronously from within an MVC controller.

What would be the "lightest" way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd issue an `HttpWebRequest` using its asynchronous methods, like `BeginGetResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are aware of the AsyncController which you can use as the base class for your MVC controller (rather than plain old Controller). This will offer you a mechanism for calling methods asynchrously. See here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/03/29/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx